# Enforcement of generic type equality constraints in method parameters

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Consider the following code sample:

```java
@SafeVarargs
public static <U> Object[] sortedCopy(Comparator<? super U> comparator, U... values) {
    U[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
    Arrays.sort(copy, comparator);
    return copy; //copy is implicitly cast to Object[] -> no heap pollution
}

public static <U> Object[] sortedCopy(U... values) {
    return sortedCopy(Comparator.naturalOrder(), values); //why does this compile???
}
```

I would have expected the compiler to reject the line in `sortedCopy(U...)`, with the following reasoning:

The return type of `Comparator.naturalOrder()` is `Comparator<T>`, where `T` is a generic type parameter of this method that must fulfill the constraint `T extends Comparable<? super T>`. Since the method does not accept any arguments, and its invocation in the above code does not explicitly specify a type for `T` (like `Comparator.<U>naturalOrder()`, which would not compile because `U` does not extend `Comparable`), `T` has to be inferred another way. The only way I can see to infer `T` is by the method signature of `sortedCopy(Comparator<? super U>, U...)`. The compiler knows the type of `values` and can thus infer `U`, and in turn can also infer bounds for `T`, namely the bounded wildcard `? super U`. But then, the compiler should realize that any `? super U` can never meet the requirement for `T` specified by `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, which is `T extends Comparable<? super T>`, because `U` itself does not extend `Comparable<? super U>`, so any supertype of `U` cannot either.

What confuses me is that the compiler *does* generate an error when I change the signature from `sortedCopy(U...)` to `sortedCopy(U[])`. I suppose this has to do with the fact that, in the second case, `U` is present at runtime as the type of the array, whereas in the first case, it is not. But I still don't understand why that would make the method call in question valid, because:

1. As I understand it, a varargs parameter of a generic type is converted to an `Object[]` if the values passed to the method as vararg arguments are of a generic and therefore non-reifiable type, which, if I understand correctly, is the case in the above code because `U` from `sortedCopy(U...)` is non-reifiable. But even then, why does the compiler not realize that `Object` does not extend `Comparable<? super Object>`?
2. The previous argument talks about runtime types. However, we're still pre-compilation, so speculations about runtime-types should not even be relevant in this context, because, while `U` might not be present anymore at runtime, the compiler still knows it and should be able to check whether the equality constraints are fulfilled, regardless of whether the method parameter is an array or a vararg.

So why does the line in question from the above code sample still compile?

Beside that, I would also be grateful for feedback in case the `@SafeVarargs` annotation of the method `sortedCopy(Comparator<? super U>, U...)` is inappropriate. I believe it is, but I'm not confident about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varargs can be a bit sneaky.  What I'm seeing in my IDE is that it's regarding `sortedCopy(U... values)` as being a *recursive* method, meaning that it's not selecting the overloaded argument with a `Comparator` as its first argument.

If you change this from varargs to array parameters, and pass in an `int[]`, you'd get the compilation failures that you would expect.

```
Error:(12, 16) no suitable method found for sortedCopy(java.util.Comparator<T>,U[])
    method Foo.<U>sortedCopy(java.util.Comparator<? super U>,U[]) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: U
        upper bound(s): java.lang.Comparable<? super U>,U,java.lang.Object)
    method Foo.<U>sortedCopy(U[]) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))

Error:(18, 47) no suitable method found for sortedCopy(java.util.Comparator<T>,int[])
    method Foo.<U>sortedCopy(java.util.Comparator<? super U>,U[]) is not applicable
      (inference variable U has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: int
        upper bounds: java.lang.Object)
    method Foo.<U>sortedCopy(U[]) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

If you pass in an `Integer[]`, or if you pass in only the vararg form, you get only the first error.

There are rules around [picking the most specific method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) available to the lexer.  Specifically, you're getting burned by this rule:

> A type S is more specific than a type T for any expression if S <: T.

In more detail:

> The subtypes of a type T are all types U such that T is a supertype of U, and the null type.

From this, we infer that, because the generic is not well-bound, **it is accepting a `Comparable` as part of your vararg.**  This is why my IDE picks it up as a recursive method, and why when I run it I get a `StackOverflowError`.

This issue actually goes away if you properly bound the generic to `<U extends Comparable<U>>` to ensure that it doesn't pick up anything you can't realistically sort on...

```
public static <U extends Comparable<U>> Object[] sortedCopy(Comparator<? super U> comparator, U... values) {
    U[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
    Arrays.sort(copy, comparator);
    return copy;
}

public static <U extends Comparable<U>> Object[] sortedCopy(U... values) {
    return sortedCopy(Comparator.naturalOrder(), values);
}
```

...with the caveat that you *might* now have heap pollution, and it'd be simpler and more concise to introduce a fixed-arity method instead.

Comment: If you change the second method name, it is clear that the first one is not invoked by `sortedCopy(Comparator.naturalOrder(), values)`

Comment: @Javier:  I'm not sure where you're going with that.  If you change the name of a method, then there's no way that there's any ambiguity.  My gut here was to preserve the intent and to correct the issue with the generics.

Comment: It was just another way of proving that "it's not selecting the overloaded argument with a Comparator as its first argument". The OP hints that `(Comparator<? super U> comparator, U... values)` is applicable for the actual parameters `(Comparator.naturalOrder(), values)` , when indeed it isn't.

Comment: @Makoto You're right, that's it. The weird thing is that my IDE (NetBeans) *did* warn me about this, but when I ran the code, I somehow managed to get a `NoSuchMethodError` thrown, so I thought the warning was a bug. Unfortunately, I have now idea how I got the `NoSuchMethodError`, because I can no longer reproduce it :( Anyway, thank you for your help. However, I don't understand how your code example at the end could introduce heap pollution. The comparator will always be able to compare the objects, regardless of their runtime type. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Stingy: I did say *might*.  I don't normally deal with varargs specifically because they produce unnecessary headaches like this, and prefer to opt for  arrays when and wherever I can.  There is [some valuable reading in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2) in regards to this scenario; I encourage you to peruse it.

Answer (score 1):

it would seem to me the function is calling itself in the scenario that cocerns to you.

in the second method, you can replace U with Object and everything fits there, since it is a varargs.